# SQL Count of programs installed not returning correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sccm

I am trying to get a count of each software installed on servers and clients. When I run the first query I get over 4000 rows returned.

```
SELECT a.DisplayName0,c.Name0 FROM v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS a, v_R_System c 
WHERE  A.DisplayName0 NOT LIKE 'hotfix for%'
AND A.DisplayName0 LIKE 'CCC Help Norwegian%'
GROUP BY c.Name0, A.DisplayName0
ORDER BY c.Name0
```

When I run this query so I can just get the count and not display each client name, it only has a count of 25 when it should be over 4000.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), a.DisplayName0,c.Name0 FROM v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS a, v_R_System c 
WHERE  A.DisplayName0 NOT LIKE 'hotfix for%'
AND A.DisplayName0 LIKE 'CCC Help Norwegian%'
GROUP BY c.Name0, A.DisplayName0
ORDER BY c.Name0
```

Any idea what might be wrong? TIA

Comment: I would start by writing out the JOIN properly. That will surely fix your issue.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: You need to provide some actual details of your tables. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're cross joining the two tables.  You'll probably need to use an INNER JOIN. I don't know what the common column is in both of the tables, but your solution will end up looking something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), a.DisplayName0,c.Name0 
FROM v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS a
INNER JOIN v_R_System c 
     ON c.<some column> = a.<some column>
WHERE  A.DisplayName0 NOT LIKE 'hotfix for%'
AND A.DisplayName0 LIKE 'CCC Help Norwegian%'
GROUP BY c.Name0, A.DisplayName0
ORDER BY c.Name0
```

Comment: I tried this but no rows are returned? SELECT COUNT(*), a.DisplayName0,c.Name0 
FROM v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS a
INNER JOIN v_R_System c 
     ON c.Name0  = a.DisplayName0
WHERE  A.DisplayName0 NOT LIKE 'hotfix for%'
AND A.DisplayName0 LIKE 'CCC Help Norwegian%'
GROUP BY c.Name0, A.DisplayName0
ORDER BY c.Name0

Comment: I tried the following but still returning 25 rows SELECT COUNT(*), a.DisplayName0,c.Name0 
FROM v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS a
INNER JOIN v_R_System c 
     ON c.ResourceID  = a.ResourceID
WHERE  A.DisplayName0 NOT LIKE 'hotfix for%'
AND A.DisplayName0 LIKE 'CCC Help Norwegian%'
GROUP BY c.Name0, A.DisplayName0
ORDER BY c.Name0

Comment: You probably want to join on some sort of an ID column between the databases.  This is usually numeric.

Comment: I did that with c.ResourceID but that just returns 25 rows when this software is installed on 4000+ clients?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the structure and data in your database.  Good luck!